# Is it worth to buy a macbook and install ubuntu on it?

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro, apple

It is my childhood dream, actually i need say i am 20, and i think buying a macbook this year, i searched on internet and wachted some videos, reading experiences about it.

desing and "name of macbook" are important for me but, if i will not get perfect experience, shouldnt buy a macbook?

problems has been listed on internet,

-wifi

-battery drain

-nvidia drivers

-...

Is it worth to buy a macbook and install ubuntu on it?

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AskUbuntu**. Well, problems are everywhere on every product.. That's how it is. I'd say its your choice. and why would you buy a Mac to install Ubuntu on it? doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: shold i buy a asus or someting else?

Comment: I bought a iMac by the same reasons as yours but I'm using it with OS X, however, tried ubuntu on it and goes very well. I don't know how can perform in a macbook.

Comment: You've not specified as to why you want to buy a mac, or what is it that you looking to achieve with Linux? Remember, it all depends with what you do and what you expect..

Comment: In my opinion mac has a beautiful design and great hardware, but if do you want a laptop with ubuntu there is a second alternative, such system76. Just compare laptops and buy what you find the best.

Comment: Opinion based questions like this one are not a good fit for this site because it's not possible to authoritatively give you one good answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which MacBook you are talking about. since the hardware differ somewhat between models.

In general terms i can tell you this from my own experience:

**Macbook Air**: Works flawlessly
I'm on MacBookAir5,2

**Macbook Retina 15**  Dual GFX card version.
HIDPI on Linux still needs a lot of work many applications look like crap.
battery time is halved because of this.
You cant switch between gfx cards without patching the grub bootloader.
No webcam support yet  *at all*

**Macbook Retina 13** 
I don't have one so can't compare
probably all of the above except for the gfx switching issue. Since it only has one card.

*A side not is that the touch pad driver is not nearly as well made as the one in osX* 
*multi touch gestures, palm & thumb detection etc, but its a lot better than it was a couple of years ago*.

**Conclusion:**
The Macbook Air is the most compatible and has the best bang for the buck.